# How to store multiple sizes for every product

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am creating an EPOS system, and need a little guidence on how to solve this issue that I have.

The retailer buys a product, and that product is available in sizes (xs, s, m, l, xl) these are default, each product has these sizes and I need to store them.

Now in the forms, when a productid is selected from the combo box, all product sizes should show up in the combo box? The question is how to store the size values in my existing table so I can use them in my application.

Eg combo box:

product id: 1234

**Size** : Please select a size:

```
       xs
       s
       m
       l
       xl
```

The product id is populated on form load and then depending on the selection the rest of the combo boxes are populated.

**Table product**

```
productid
description
quantity
price
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create a new table in the database and how to set up the relationship? or how to add the size values to your existing table?

Comment: how to add the size values to my existing table.

Comment: If “all product sizes should show up in the combo box” then why not create a comboBox in the UI with all product sizes? Why do you need to do anything with the database if all products have all product sizes?

Comment: That is one option, but I wanted to figure out how to do it in the database. no harm in learning?

Comment: Also if a product box in UI is created with the sizes, how will the admin be able to change the sizes in the back end? @DourHighArch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the comments, I think I have figured it out for my needs.

**Table product**
  id
  description
  sizeCatId

**Table size_category**

sizeCatId

sizes

```
SELECT product.productid,
product.description,
product.sizeCatId,
size_category.sizes
FROM
product
INNER JOIN size_category ON product.sizeCatId = size_category.sizeCatId
WHERE
product.productid = 1
```

I will join on sizeCatId, which will contain whichever sizes associated with that ID. The reason this approach is chosen is because I want to avoid hard coding any values in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate table like this one:

```
productid
size
```

Then you will be able to use **SQL JOIN** in order to find sizes of your products.

Comment: will this have all sizes associated with a product ie product1 = sizes s, m, l, xl?

Comment: Yes, you can insert values inside that table in format like:
`__productid__ | __size__` and have multiple productids with different sizes.